# How can I goto a function definition imported from another file using jedi-vim?

Tags: vim, jedi-vim

I regularly use `<leader>d` to go to a function definition.  When this definition is from another file, it brings me to the import line of the file.

How can I use jedi-vim to go to the file that defines the function imported on that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like there is something wrong with your configuration... Double check that your `filetype` is indeed `python`.  This should work, according to [the documentation](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/blob/master/doc/jedi-vim.txt#L240):

> 5.2. `g:jedi#goto_command`
>
> Function: `jedi#goto()`
>
> Default: `<leader>d`
>
> Go to definition (or assignment)
>
> This function first tries `jedi#goto_definitions`, and falls back to
>   `jedi#goto_assignments` for builtin modules.  It produces an error if
>   nothing could be found. NOTE: this implementation is subject to
>   change. Ref: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/570
>
> This command tries to find the original definition of the
>   function/class under the cursor. Just like the
>   `jedi#goto_assignments()` function, it does not work if the definition
>   isn't in a Python source file.
>
> The difference between `jedi#goto_assignments()` and
>   `jedi#goto_definitions()` is that the latter performs recursive
>   lookups. Take, for example, the following module structure:
>
> ```
> # file1.py:
> from file2 import foo
>
> # file2.py:
> from file3 import bar as foo
>
> # file3.py
> def bar():
>     pass
> ```
>
> The `jedi#goto_assignments()` function will take you to the
>
> ```
> from file2 import foo
> ```
>
> statement in file1.py, while the `jedi#goto_definitions()` function
>   will take you all the way to the
>
> ```
> def bar():
> ```
>
> line in file3.py.

Comment: You are correct.  It does work with installed libraries.  I didn't realize this.  The problem is with libraries I've written.  I'm going to ask another question related to this problem.

Comment: The other question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235611/using-goto-with-user-defined-modules-in-jedi-vim.